# Implementation of `Exception.__str__()` in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I've never fully understood exception handling in Python (or any language to be honest). I was experimenting with custom exceptions, and found the following behaviour.

```
class MyError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, anything):
        pass

me = MyError("iiiiii")
print(me)
```

Output:

```
iiiiii
```

I assume that `print()` calls `Exception.__str__()`.

How does the base class `Exception` know to print `iiiiii`? The string `"iiiiii"` was passed to the constructor of `MyError` via the argument `anything`, but `anything` isn't stored anywhere in `MyError` at all!

Furthermore, the constructor of `MyError` does not call its superclass's (Exception's) constructor. So, how did `print(me)` print `iiiiii`?

Comment: What version of Python? This can't be reproduced in Python 2.7.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, Python 3.5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, the `BaseException` class has a `__new__` method that stores the arguments in `self.args`:

```
>>> me.args
('iiiiii',)
```

You didn't override the `__new__` method, only `__init__`. You'd need to override **both** to completely prevent from `self.args` to be set, as both implementations happily set that attribute:

```
>>> class MyError(Exception):
...     def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
...         return super().__new__(cls)  # ignoring args and kwargs!
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
...         super().__init__()           # again ignoring args and kwargs
...
>>> me = MyError("iiiiii")
>>> me
MyError()
>>> print(me)

>>> me.args
()
```

In Python 2, exceptions do not implement `__new__` and your sample would not print anything. See [issue #1692335](https://bugs.python.org/issue1692335) as to why the `__new__` method was added; basically to avoid issues like yours where the `__init__` method does not also call `super().__init__()`.

Note that `__init__` is not a *constructor*; the instance is already constructed by that time, by `__new__`. `__init__` is merely the *initialiser*.